# What happens if I upgrade 2X2 GB RAM in my laptop to 2X4 GB?

Tags: laptop, memory, graphics-card, performance

My Laptop has following specs :-

2X2 GB RAM (2.99 GB usable)
Intel core i5 @2.4 GHz quad core processor (2nd generation...maybe )
1 GB Graphics card (utilizing memory from RAM)
EDIT : 1) Also 32-bit Win-7 OS

So what will happen if I upgrade my RAM to 2X4 GB ?

Will my laptop have 6 GB RAM + 2 GB graph ? OR
7 GB RAM + 1GB graph ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean that you are using HDA graphics embedded in the i5 CPU.

The memory size used by this chip is fixed, and adding momre memory won't change how much is used by the GPU.

So you will end up with 7GB available to your OS (if it's the 64bit version !) and still 1GB for your graphics.

Please note that the graphic performance of a computer is not much affected but how much memory its GPU has. it's more affected by the calculaiton power of the GPU. That is how many Vortex/Pixel shaders, its clock frequency, etc. Since you're using a laptop, there not much chance you can drastically increase its graphical performance.

Comment: edited my question I have 32-bit win-7 OS

Comment: Then your total memory is limited to about 3.6GB, so unless you reinstall your OS with the 64bit version, there's no reason to change its memory chips.

Comment: I don't know much about this topic....so, please tell me how good is my processor in the field of gaming(games like GTA 5 or Battlefield 4)

Comment: @MukulKumar - Horrible.  You need to be made aware that GTA5 will only work on 64-bit operating systems.  Your CPU is the bottom of the barrel when it comes to performance ( today ) and was always bottom of the barrel because of the GPU.

Comment: @Ramhound That hurt me(b'cuz I used to know most in my group about computers and all), but now I realize that I need to know a lot more...Thanks a lot for reply...